# how hive is running without hive-site.xml file?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to set up hive on my local. I started all Hadoop processes and set up the {hive}/bin path. On command prompt I can run hive commands , create and read tables. My questions are -

1) is hive-site.xml is optional file ?
2) in absence of hive-site.xml file, how hive get information regrading metastore and other configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Hive queries from your local machine which has Hadoop installed, `hive-site.xml` is not needed as you are talking directly to `hive/bin` in the Hive installation directory. You don't need to tell Hive where to find Hive.

If you wanted to run Hive commands from another machine, but interacting with Hive on your local machine, you'd need `hive-site.xml`.

Comment: Thanks @Ben.then I am assuming that Hive will use default config , in case no hive-site.xml, like namenode adress:port. But hive is working even when I am changing the port (other than default) for namenode process in core-site.xml. I am wondering how Hive know where hdfs is running without config file?

Comment: continue ... 
BUT if remove the hadoop home from paths, it is giving below complain. So can I conclude here that in case hive-site.xml isn't there, for local hive will read hdfs details from HADOOP_HOME path?
Error - 'Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path'